# Powershell Mulitple variables to Out-File

Tags: powershell

I would like to output a line to my .txt file/log file that basically grabs the path of `$source` then says *"is compared too"* the path of `$compare`. But when I do this with `Out-File` they overwrite each other. For instance, if I was to do `$source | Out-File $log` with only the path before the recurse the next `Out-File` over writes it. So by the end of my script when I look at my log all that is there is the `Compare-Object | Out-File $log`I use below.

```
   #prompts user for input through cmd for path of log file
    $log = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input path of log, if log does not, create one. Include file name and extension' 

    #prompts user for input through cmd, saves path, then recursively searches
    $source = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input source path'  
    $source = gci $source -recurse

    #prompts user for input through cmd, saves path, then recursively searches
    $compare = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the path of directory to compare' 
    $compare = gci $compare -recurse

    #compares the $source to the $compare and outputs to log file 

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $source -DifferenceObject $compare -PassThru | Out-File $log -width 120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-Append` parameter to add text to a file without overwriting it.

```
Out-File $log -width 120 -Append
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I overlooked that.

Comment: No problem, can you accept the answer if it has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-Append` parameter will append your text as a new line.

If you want to have the Text part (x is compared to y) in one Line you will have to assemble the String before outputting it. For example:

```
"$source is compared to $compare :" | out-file $log -width 120
$comparison | out-file $log -width 120 -Append
```